# JQuery add field value to corresponding variable

Tags: jquery

I would like JQuery to scan through all of the input fields on a form, and add the values of the user input to a corresponding variable (which I intend to use later in a summary report).

So far I have the following code, but I am not sure how to finish it:

```
// next step
    $('.quote-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {
        var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        var next_step = true;

        //add value of field to corresponding variable
        parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
            if( $(this).val() !== "" ) {

            }
        });     
    });
```

I would like the function to loop through each input, create a variable with the same name as the input field's name, and assign the value of that field to the variable it creates. Finally I would like to be able to use those variable in the last fieldset of my form to build a summary of all the inputs the user entered.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assign each of the input elements a unique id. Outside of the loop initialize an empty object:

```
var summary = {};
```

Then, in your loop, do this:

```
var id = $(this).id;
var value = $(this).val();

summary[id] = value;
```

To retrieve it:

```
$('#someElement').text(summary["#price"]);
```

Comment: Thank you. My next question would be how do I pull a value from the summary object and insert it into a field (so I can build the summary page)?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I am actually getting an error with you solution. The console is sending me this: Uncaught ReferenceError: summary is not defined

Comment: @K.Carskadon you need to define `var summary = {};` in the global scope (i.e. outside of any function) or else it will be destroyed after the event handler

Comment: How would I print the values of the summary object to the console so I can see if it is retaining the values?

Comment: @K.Carskadon umm... what about `console.log(summary)`